# Where do I find Stingers and Sentinels after completing the main quest?

Tags: darksiders-2

Where do I find Stingers and Sentinels? I've finished Drenchfort and the Lost Temple. I need them for the Shaman sidequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stingers can be found in the passage from The Fjord back to the main area. If you go to The Fjord waypoint, head North, and go through the gate you opened earlier, there is a Stinger hive on the other side.

I don't remember seeing any wild Sentinels, but you will run into them again later. You can also find them by battling in the Crucible. They will show up in the third set of five rounds. However, I don't know if you can get the quest item in the Crucible.

Comment: Erm, how much later? I've just completed the Lost Temple.

Comment: You'll still find more after that. Oh! Just remembered another place to find them, adding it to the answer.

Comment: Don't have access to The Crucible as of yet.

Comment: Ah, alright. I couldn't remember when you gained access.

Comment: I can confirm Stingers in the crucible drop the required item for the quest. Are there Construct Sentinels in the Crucible?

Answer (score 4):

The stingers can be found here:
[image]
There will be a lot of wasp-like creatures flying around and a hive. Kill the wasps and the hive and you'll get the `Mordant Dew` for the quest.

The sentinels can be found in the Lost Temple: 
[image]

When you go through the dungeon you will come to a point with floating, stone heads that you need to kill. Kill them, and the monsters they spawn to get the last item for the quest.

If you're still unsure of where these are and what specifically you need to look for, take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HQXXSRox8A) (starts at 24 seconds). Furthermore you can talk to `Karn` who will give you instructions on where to find the items.

Comment: Will they still spawn in the Lost Temple if you've already finished it?

Comment: ^ Exactly my question.

Comment: Had to go back to see but apparantly not, good thing there's still the Crucible then i guess :)

Comment: But I've already done the crucible too :( am I just screwed?

Comment: @user43535 The crucible is repeatable iirc

Answer (score 1):

Just to let everyone know, the Crucible is the place to go for the entire quest, it offers all three of the quest items you need for the Shaman's Quest
(Waves 6, 7, and 13)

Answer (score 0):

The Stingers, as mentioned, can be find at the end of the Shadow Gorge near the Fjord.

A single Sentinel can also be found near the end of the Shattered Forge found in the Shadow Gorge. It's an optional mini-dungeon explored in The Hammer’s Forge quest)